# How to properly switch between complex Backbone Apps in a One-Page App

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm having several complex views/apps that all together form one big app.

Think of gmail, where you have mail and contacts
Or twitter, switching from profile view to settings
In my case, it's a game where you can have a view to play and a map editor.

I'd like to switch between them without reload inside THE big main app.

Now I am struggeling with a concept on how to achieve two things:

- How to switch properly (unbinding events, tearing down all views) without leaks
- How to organize the routing, when all sub-apps can have their navigation items.

Concrete question:

There is a gameApp and an editorApp

If I am on "#game/12345/details/" and switch to "#editor/map/123", the following should happen:

1) Main router notices the app switch
2) tears down the game app and all subviews/events
3) switches and initializes editorApp
4) editorApp routes to map 123, loading the data

How would the main Router look like, taking the additional route params into account
Should I use subrouters?
Should I maybe leave the gameApp in Memory and just hide it?
How would a function look like to handle the routing?

I know this is a lot of stuff, but maybe you can direct me on a tutorial/design pattern/.. site?

This [Cleaning views with backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079491/cleaning-views-with-backbone-js/9139131#9139131) seems to be an option for switching apps, but it would not help on the subroutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on the great Backbone.Marionette and the reference application BBCloneMail:

https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette
https://github.com/derickbailey/bbclonemail

Comment: Thanks, I'll be looking into it