# BackboneJS remove old view on back?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, pushstate

I have a BackboneJS app and it has a router for two different views. The problem is if I go from one view to another it works fine, but if I click the back button on my browser it just adds one of the views on top of the other. (So I end up with both views showing).

How can I remove the views or force a refresh?

```
  var Schedule = Parse.Object.extend({
    className: "schedule"
  });

  var Movie = Parse.Object.extend({
    className: "movie"
  });

  var ScheduleList = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: Schedule
  });

  var schedule = new ScheduleList();
  var movie = new Movie();

  var ScheduleView = Parse.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
          schedule.query = new Parse.Query(Schedule);
          schedule.query.ascending("date");
          schedule.query.limit('500');

          var render = this.render;

      schedule.fetch({
        success: function() {
          render(schedule.toJSON());
        }
      });
    },

    render: function(schedule) {
      console.log(schedule);
      var template = Handlebars.compile($("#schedule-item").html());
      $("#schedule-holder").html(template({shows: schedule}));
      return this;
    }
  });

  var MovieView = Parse.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      var query = new Parse.Query(Movie);
      query.equalTo("mId", parseInt(this.id));
      query.limit('1');

      var render = this.render;

      query.first({
        success: function(details) {
          render(details.toJSON());
        }
      });
    },

    render: function(movie) {
      var template = Handlebars.compile($("#movie-item").html());
      $("#movie-holder").html(template(movie));
      return this;
    }
  });

  var AppRouter = Parse.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "movie/:id": "movieDetails",
            "*actions": "schedule" // Backbone will try match the route above first
        },
        movieDetails: function( id ) {
            // Note the variable in the route definition being passed in here
            var App = new MovieView({ id: id });
        },
        schedule: function( actions ){
            var App = new ScheduleView();
        }
    });

  // Instantiate the router
  var app_router = new AppRouter;

  // Start Backbone history a neccesary step for bookmarkable URL's
  Parse.history.start();
```

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079491/cleaning-views-with-backbone-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your router should keep track of the current view (if any) and call [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on the old view before adding the new one. The default `remove` is pretty simple:

> **remove** `view.remove()`
>
> Convenience function for removing the view from the DOM. Equivalent to calling `$(view.el).remove();`.

That will clear out the HTML and, since [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) binds a [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to the view's `el` for event handling, calling `remove` will also prevent zombie UI events. You'd probably want to unbind any event handlers that have been bound to models or collections in your `remove` as well, otherwise you can get zombie views hidden in data event handlers.

You might not want `remove` to remove anything from the DOM, you might just want things like:

```
remove: function() {
    this.$el.empty();
    this.undelegateEvents();
    return this;
}
```

then the view's `el` will stay in the DOM but it won't cause any problems.

So, add `remove` implementations as need to your views and adjust your router to call `remove`:

```
var AppRouter = Parse.Router.extend({
    //...
    initialize: function() {
        this.view = null;
    },
    movieDetails: function( id ) {
        this._cleanUp();
        this.view = new MovieView({ id: id });
        //...
    },
    schedule: function( actions ){
        this._cleanUp();
        this.view = new ScheduleView();
        //...
    },
    _cleanUp: function() {
        if(this.view)
            this.view.remove();
        this.view = null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a controller ( or use the router as the controller ) or a master view to control this functionality.

Then when each route is triggered pass the newly created route to said controller or master view.

```
var Controller = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#masterdiv'
      showView: function ( view ) {
         this.$el.empty().append( view.el );
      } 
});
var controller = new Controller();
var AppRouter = Parse.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "movie/:id": "movieDetails",
            "*actions": "schedule" // Backbone will try match the route above first
        },
        movieDetails: function( id ) {
            // Note the variable in the route definition being passed in here
            var view = new MovieView({ id: id });
            controller.showView( view );
        },
        schedule: function( actions ){
            var view = new ScheduleView();
            controller.showView( view );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation this was my first backbone.js app and I could have added some more modularity to it for sure.