# Detect browsers back button in backbonejs

Tags: button, backbone.js, browser, back

simple question, how can i detect the event of the browsers back button in backbonejs?

In my app, if i press the back button it will jump directly to the route before. But i must trigger the click to make some animations.

How can i solve this?

The one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181512/backbonejs-remove-old-view-on-back) can't solve my problem, because i must wait of some animations, doing in the .remove() method.

I use all current versions of [jquery, underscore, backbone].

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use backbone.routerFilter, you can fire events before the handler for the route gets called, and keep track of the users navegation there.

https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter

trying to detect the borwsers back button seems difficult as your code may not work the same across browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But i leave it alone, its to difficult and the benefit is to small.